# Attempt to redefine project facet action

Tags: eclipse

eclipse.buildId=4.4.2.M20150204-1700

java.version=1.7.0_80

java.vendor=Oracle Corporation

BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US

Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

Attempt to redefine project facet action "osgi.bundle.uninstall" in plugin org.eclipse.libra.facet.

when try to do MAVEN clean i am getting

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/maven/cli/MavenCli : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at org..............................................................

Please help !!!

Comment: Code was build in 1.6 and i have checked ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES, COMPILER all are set to 1.6 still its throwing error.

Comment: Unless you're compiling org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli, which is the class that has an unsupported version, changing those things will not make a difference. You need to run Maven using 1.7.